# How to include if-else statements into reactive flow

Tags: java, spring-webflux, project-reactor

I have a Spring Webflux reactive service which receives a DTO and inserts it into multiple table.
Sometimes we may need to skip inserting into some tables based on the incoming DTO.

These are the requirements:

1. Create a new Client
2. Create a new Client referral if the client referral is present in the DTO.
3. Create a client Secondary contact if present in the DTO
4. Create client phones if present in the DTO

**Questions:-**

1. Not sure how to apply the if condition in the reactive flow.
2. Is there any better way of doing this?
3. Here, except the first one all other operation can run in parallel.

```
public Mono<ServerResponse> createClientProfile(ServerRequest request) {
        return secContext.retrieveUser().flatMap(usr -> {
            return request.bodyToMono(ClientDto.class).flatMap(client -> {
                return toNewClient(client, usr).flatMap(clientRepository::save).flatMap(clientRes -> {
                    return toNewClientReferral(clientRes.getClientId(), client.getDiscount(), usr)
                            .flatMap(clientReferralRepository::save).flatMap(clientReferralRes -> {
                                return toNewClientSyContact(clientRes.getClientId(), client.getSecondary(), usr)
                                        .flatMap(clientSyContactRepository::save).flatMap(clientSyContactRes -> {
                                            return clientPhoneRepository
                                                    .saveAll(toNewClientPhone(clientRes.getClientId(), client.getPhones(), usr))
                                                    .collectList().flatMap(phoneRes -> {
                                                        return ServerResponse
                                                                .created(URI.create(String.format(CLIENT_URI_FORMAT,
                                                                        clientRes.getClientId())))
                                                                .contentType(APPLICATION_JSON).build();
                                                    });
                                        });
                            });
                });
            });
        });

    }

private Mono<Referral> toNewClientReferral(final long clientId, final Discount dto) {
        Referral referral = Referral.of(clientId, 
                dto.getName(), dto.getType(), dto.getAmount(), dto.getStatus());

        return Mono.just(referral);
    }
```

> client.getDiscount() can be null,
> client.getSecondary() can be null,
> client.getPhones() can be empty.

I separated the flow with 3 different methods.

```
public void createSyContact(ServerRequest request, long clientId) {
        secContext.retrieveUser().flatMap(usr -> {
            return request.bodyToMono(ClientDto.class).flatMap(client -> {
                if (client.getSecondary() != null) {
                    return toNewClientSyContact(clientId, client.getSecondary(), usr)
                            .flatMap(clientSyContactRepository::save).flatMap(clientRes -> {
                                return Mono.just(clientRes.getClientId());
                            });
                } else {
                    return Mono.empty();
                }
            });
        });
    }

    public void createReferral(ServerRequest request, long clientId) {
        secContext.retrieveUser().flatMap(usr -> {
            return request.bodyToMono(ClientDto.class).flatMap(client -> {
                if (client.getDiscount() != null) {
                    return toNewClientReferral(clientId, client.getDiscount(), usr)
                            .flatMap(clientReferralRepository::save).flatMap(clientRes -> {
                                return Mono.just(clientRes.getClientId());
                            });
                } else {
                    return Mono.empty();
                }
            });
        });
    }

    public Mono<Long> createClientWithPhones(ServerRequest request) {
        return secContext.retrieveUser().flatMap(usr -> {
            return request.bodyToMono(ClientDto.class).flatMap(client -> {
                return toNewClient(client, usr).flatMap(clientRepository::save).flatMap(clientRes -> {
                    return clientPhoneRepository
                            .saveAll(toNewClientPhone(clientRes.getClientId(), client.getPhones(), usr)).collectList()
                            .flatMap(phoneRes -> {
                                return Mono.just(clientRes.getClientId());
                            });
                });
            });
        });
    }
```

Here, createClientWithPhones is mandatory, so no if check there. But the other 2 methods createReferral & createSyContact have if checks. Need to execute createClientWithPhones first and it will return clientId. This clientId should be used in createReferral & createSyContact.

```
public Mono<ServerResponse> createClientProfile(ServerRequest request) {
        final List<Long> clinetIdList = new ArrayList<>();
        createClientWithPhones(request).subscribe(result -> {
            clinetIdList.add(result.longValue());
            createSyContact(request, result.longValue());
            createReferral(request, result.longValue());
        });
        return ServerResponse
                .created(URI.create(String.format(CLIENT_URI_FORMAT,
                        clinetIdList.get(0))))
                .contentType(APPLICATION_JSON).build();
        
    }
```

Is this the way to handle this?

Comment: So, there are ways, but I think if-else is "procedural" and reactive is functional. If you're stuck and cannot include procedural code, then you need to get inventive. Generally I see code that handles an empty flow with a `switchIfEmpty` or `defaultIfEmpty` and the if-else converts to if-not-empty-else-if-empty.

Comment: I need only if. If the client referral is present, save that and proceed with the next one. If not present, exclude that and proceed with the next one.

Comment: Isn't that a filtering function?

Comment: @K.Nicholas Not sure how can we do filtering here.

Comment: Are you using a reactive repository?

Comment: Yes, Spring data r2dbc. Its reactive end to end. public interface UserRepository extends ReactiveCrudRepository<User, Long>

Comment: you have a race condition in the `createClientProfile` method. The `ServerResponse` method could be invoked before `createClientWithPhones` has completed as it is executed at assembly time, not as part of the reactive chain. You'll most likely get IndexOutOfBounds exceptions with this code.

Comment: Correct. Not sure how to improve with this approach. It works with the first approach and having issues with broken approach.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Well, I don't think there is a good understanding in general of the reactive library. What I mean is that generally people approach like Java 8 streams in that they are trying to do functional programming. Of course the reactive library is based in functional programming, but I think the purpose is to be asynchronous around blocking I/O. Consider the (current) front page of the WebFlux project.

> What is reactive processing?
> Reactive processing is a paradigm that enables developers build non-blocking, asynchronous applications that can handle back-pressure (flow control).

So, this is a longwinded way of saying I think it is better to focus on where the I/O is happening rather than creating functional code. If you need `if` statements, then you need `if` statements. Instead of trying to figure out how to do `if` statements with functional programming try to figure out where the I/O is taking place and handle it in an asynchronous fashion. One "trick" I like to use is `Mono::zip` or `Flux::zip`. These functions combine many I/O calls into one publisher to be returned to the client. So, consider this example code.

Let's make some reactive r2dbc functions:

```
Mono<Client> save(Client client) {
    client.id = 1L;
    System.out.println("Save client: " + client.id);
    return Mono.just(client);
}
Mono<Phone> save(Phone phone) {
    System.out.println("Save phone: " + phone.clientId);
    return Mono.just(phone);
}
Mono<Referral> save(Referral referral) {
    System.out.println("Save referral: " + referral.clientId);
    return Mono.just(referral);
}
Mono<Contact> save(Contact contact) {
    System.out.println("Save contact: " + contact.clientId);
    return Mono.just(contact);
}
```

We need some example classes to use:

```
class DTO {
    Client client;
    List<Phone> phones;
    Optional<Contact> contact;
    Optional<Referral> referral;
}

class Client {
    Long id;
}

class Contact {
    Long clientId;
}

class Referral {
    Long clientId;
}

class Phone {
    Long clientId;
}
```

Our input is probably a `Mono<DTO>` since that is what the Request should supply, so our `Service` layer needs to start with that and return a `Mono<Long>` of the client id.

```
Mono<Long> doWork(Mono<DTO> monoDto) {
    return monoDto.flatMap(dto->{
        return save(dto.client).flatMap(client->{
            List<Mono<?>> publishers = new ArrayList<>();
            dto.phones.forEach(phone->{
                phone.clientId = client.id;
                publishers.add(save(phone));    
            });
            if ( dto.contact.isPresent()) {
                Contact c = dto.contact.get();
                c.clientId = client.id;
                publishers.add(save(c));
            }
            if ( dto.referral.isPresent()) {
                Referral r = dto.referral.get();
                r.clientId = client.id;
                publishers.add(save(r));
            }
            if ( publishers.size() > 0 )
                return Mono.zip(publishers, obs->client.id);
            else
                return Mono.just(client.id);
        });
    });
}
```

I ran this with the following example code:

```
@Override
public void run(ApplicationArguments args) throws Exception {
    saveClient(new Client(), null, null, null).subscribe(System.out::println);
    saveClient(new Client(), new Phone(), null, null).subscribe(System.out::println);
    saveClient(new Client(), new Phone(), new Contact(), null).subscribe(System.out::println);
    saveClient(new Client(), new Phone(), new Contact(), new Referral()).subscribe(System.out::println);
}


private Mono<Long> saveClient(Client client, Phone phone, Contact contact,
        Referral referral) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    DTO dto = new DTO();
    dto.client = client;
    dto.phones = new ArrayList<>();
    if ( phone != null ) dto.phones.add(phone);     
    dto.contact = Optional.ofNullable(contact);
    dto.referral = Optional.ofNullable(referral);
    return doWork(Mono.just(dto));
}
```

So, this uses the `Mono.zip` trick. The saved client is flatmapped so that is done first. Then a list of monos is created for all subsequent saves that need to be done. These monos are all executed asynchronously by the Mono.zip function. The "combiner" function does nothing with the results, it just returns the clientId which is what is wanted for the client. The Mono.zip combines all the Monos into a single Mono to return to the client. In a sense this is just taking procedural code and wrapping it in the reactive library rather than getting overly focused on functional programming. This is easy to read and modify if the business "process" changes going forward.

This is a starting point if you like it. I didn't use `Repository::saveAll` so that could be an improvement.

It's important to be sure all your `Flux` and `Mono` publishers are chained together. In your final example you seemed to be dropping them. Simply creating them is not enough, they all have to be returned to the client somehow. Also, your code has a `subscribe` call which is a no-no. Only the client should have subscribe. I think you should have used a `map` there.

EDIT: Fixed a bug. Check your code carefully.

EDIT II: I noticed that I used an "Optional" as a parameter in the class. This is an anti-pattern. The correct way is to use the type as the parameter and wrap it in an "Optional.of" in a special getter.

Answer (score 5):

a plain if-statement can be done for instance in a `flatMap` and then acted upon.

```
public Mono<String> foobar() {
    return Mono.just("foo").flatMap(value -> {
        if(value != null)
            return Mono.just("Has value");
        else
            return Mono.empty();
    }
}

foobar()
    .switchIfEmpty(Mono.just("Is empty"))
    .subscribe(output -> System.out.println(output);
```

Comment: I have updated my answer based on this. I am still doing something wrong. Is there any better way?

Answer (score 2):

You can use a combination of `filter` and `switchIfEmpty`. I think it's a quite concise and readable approach.

```
public void write(String content) {
  Mono.just(content)
    .filter(s -> !s.isBlank())
    .switchIfEmpty(Mono.just("No content"))
    .subscribe(System.out::println);
}
```

`filter` takes a predicate to test the supplied value. If the predicate evaluates to false then it will complete without a value and `switchIfEmpty` will be called.